# Error while embedding string using spring-ai

Tags: spring-boot, embedding, spring-ai

I am using Spring-AI to embed string into vector. Here is the code snippet

```
@Autowired
private EmbeddingClient embeddingClient;

String text = title + " " + overview;
List<Double> embeddings = embeddingClient.embed(text);
```

I am getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [org.springframework.ai.openai.api.OpenAiApi$EmbeddingList<org.springframework.ai.openai.api.OpenAiApi$Embedding>] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient.readWithMessageConverters(DefaultRestClient.java:231) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultResponseSpec.readBody(DefaultRestClient.java:659) ~[spring-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]

Caused by: java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1796) ~[na:na]
```

What could be the probable issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, at last I was able to solve the error.

I just needed to  add the following dependency into the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it will help others if they face such issues.